# Laravel pass variable from controller query to model function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a function on my model that check active status in equipment_station table,

originally it only checked one status, now i need to pass a parameter to the model with active or inactive values, I've tried this with no success.

controller:
[image: controller query]

model :
  [image: model image]

How can i change the parameter in the model, I send status from controller as inactive or active.

thanks in advance

Comment: could you paste the code instead of upload a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You could you [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
public function scopeActive($query, $active)
{
   return $query->where('active', $active);
}
```

then you can call it in your model

```
Estacion::active(true)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Constraint [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) by specifying additional query constraints for the eager loading

```
$historial_estaction = 
Estacion::where('estacion.id', $id)
   ->whereHas('equipos', function($query) use ($estado1) {
        $query->where('equipo_estacion.estado', $estado1);
    })->with(['equipos' => function ($query) use ($estado1) {
        $query->where('estado', $estado1);
    }])->get();
```

Model:

```
public function equipos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipo')
                ->withPivot('estado')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```